# Using os.walk in order to recurse into folders in Python

Tags: python, recursion, filesystems

I have the following code as part of a Python file, and it traverses .py files in the folder called controllers, and preforms some operations with them.

This is my prototype, but now I want to use [os.walk](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) to recurse into the folders.

```
controller_folder_path = "applications/%s/controllers/*.py" % application_name
for module_path in glob.glob(controller_folder_path):
    print module_path
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

controller_folder_path = "applications/%s/controllers" % application_name
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(controller_folder_path):
    for module_path in files:
        module_path = os.path.join(root, module_path)
        if module_path.endswith('.py'):
            print module_path
```

Answer (score 1):

os.walk will return an iterable of 3-tuples for every directory and subdirectory in the specified top directory.

```
from os import walk

dirs = walk('/top/directory/here')
for path_from_top, subdirs, files in dirs:
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('py'):
            print str(path_from_top) + '/' + str(f)
```